# How to get the Values of recently inserted columns from Temporary Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am not able to use the recently inserted `Quantity` value of `#ACCT` table in the Select statement to be used like

```
ser.ServiceRate * Quantity
```

Every time I get the ERROR

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Amount'

I am just a beginner so any pointers to solve this would help.

```
DECLARE @MinReservationId INT = (SELECT MIN(f.ReservationId) FROM dbo.Reservation AS f)
DECLARE @MaxReservationId INT = (SELECT MAX(f.ReservationId) FROM dbo.Reservation AS f)
DECLARE @QuantityNew INT

WHILE @MinReservationId <= @MaxReservationId
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Acct
    (
        ServiceId INT,
        Quantity INT --> I WANT THIS VALUE TO BE USED BELOW
    )

    INSERT INTO dbo.[Transaction]
(
    ReservationId,
    ServiceId,
    Rate,
    Quantity,
    Amount      
)   
OUTPUT inserted.ServiceId,Inserted.Quantity
INTO #Acct
(
    ServiceId,
    Quantity
)
SELECT 
    @MinReservationId,
    ser.ServiceId,
    ser.ServiceRate,
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%3) + 1,
    ser.ServiceRate * (SELECT acc.Quantity from #Acct as acc) -> QUANTITY from #ACCT should be used here 
FROM dbo.[Service] AS ser

SELECT @MinReservationId=@MinReservationId+1
Drop table #Acct
END
```

Comment: By the time of insertion `#Acct`table is empty, so `SELECT acc.Quantity from #Acct as acc` returns just a `NULL` value. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Oh!  `Quantity` value is what I want so that I can use it in the below Select statement. `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%3) + 1` generates a random value for quantity and I want that same quantity value to be multiplied with `ser.ServiceRate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` in order to capture the `NEWID()` value created for every record of table `dbo.[Service]`. Then use this `CTE` to do the `INSERT`:

```
;WITH ToInsert AS 
(
   SELECT ServiceId ,
          ServiceRate,
          ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%3) + 1 AS Quantity 
   FROM dbo.[Service] 
)
INSERT INTO dbo.[Transaction]
(
    ReservationId,
    ServiceId,
    Rate,
    Quantity,
    Amount      
)   
SELECT @MinReservationId,
       ServiceId,
       ServiceRate,
       Quantity,
       ServiceRate *  Quantity
FROM ToInsert
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Giorgos. it works perfectly. I did not even know about CTE until now. :)