# Using Multiple CTE with one INSERT statement. [Error:More Columns than Specified in Column List]

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

I have CTE1 and CTE2 as below. The CTE2 shows error

`CTE2 has more columns than specified in the column list`

I  would like to know what I am doing wrong. It cannot be because Insert statement has more columns than the CTE2 because CTE1 worked fine before. CTE1 and CTE2 are both using different tables. Is that the problem?

If I remove the parameters in `CTE2(NewRoomCost,NewQuantity)` Then I get the error

`No Columns specified for Column3 of CTE2`

Below is the code that I tried. Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SpTransactionGenerate
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @MinReservationId INT = (SELECT MIN(f.ReservationId) FROM dbo.Reservation AS f)
    DECLARE @MaxReservationId INT = (SELECT MAX(f.ReservationId) FROM dbo.Reservation AS f)

    DECLARE @FirstSeasonEndDate DATE= '2018-02-13';
    DECLARE @SecondSeasonEndDate DATE='2018-02-14';
    DECLARE @ThirdSeasonEndDate DATE='2018-12-31';

    WHILE @MinReservationId<=@MaxReservationId
    BEGIN   
        WITH CTE1(ServiceId,ServiceRate,Quantity) AS 
        (
           SELECT ServiceId,
                  ServiceRate,
                  ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%3) + 1 AS Quantity 
           FROM dbo.[Service]                              
        ),
        CTE2(NewRoomCost,NewQuantity) AS 
        (
           SELECT 
                (SELECT roomRate.RoomCost FROM dbo.RoomRate as roomRate WHERE roomRate.RoomTypeId=
                (SELECT room.RoomTypeId FROM dbo.Room as room
                JOIN dbo.Reservation as res ON res.RoomId=room.RoomId WHERE res.ReservationId=@MinReservationId
                AND roomRate.SeasonId=(
                CASE WHEN (SELECT resv.CheckInDate FROM dbo.Reservation as resv WHERE resv.ReservationId=@MinReservationId)<=@FirstSeasonEndDate
                THEN (SELECT sea.SeasonId FROM dbo.Season as sea WHERE sea.SeasonEndDate=@FirstSeasonEndDate)
                WHEN (SELECT resv.CheckInDate FROM dbo.Reservation as resv WHERE resv.ReservationId=@MinReservationId)<=@SecondSeasonEndDate
                THEN (SELECT sea.SeasonId FROM dbo.Season as sea WHERE sea.SeasonEndDate=@SecondSeasonEndDate)
                ELSE (SELECT sea.SeasonId FROM dbo.Season as sea WHERE sea.SeasonEndDate=@ThirdSeasonEndDate) END
                )
                )) AS NewRoomCost,

                DATEDIFF(DAY,(SELECT r.CheckinDate FROM dbo.Reservation AS r WHERE r.ReservationId=@MinReservationId), (SELECT r.CheckOutDate FROM dbo.Reservation AS r WHERE r.ReservationId=@MinReservationId)) AS NewQuantity,                                                  
        )

        INSERT INTO dbo.[Transaction]
        (
            ReservationId,
            ServiceId,
            Rate,
            Quantity,
            Amount              
        )   
        SELECT 
            @MinReservationId,
            ServiceId,
            ServiceRate,
            Quantity,
            ServiceRate*Quantity
            FROM CTE1
            UNION
        SELECT 
            @MinReservationId,
            NULL,
            NewRoomCost,
            NewQuantity,
            NewRoomCost*NewQuantity
            FROM CTE2

        SELECT @MinReservationId=@MinReservationId+1    
    END
END
```

UPDATE : The error resulted because of a single extra comma in the CTE2. Sorry for the unnecessary question asked.

Comment: Why the ctes and the union.  Just do the two inserts directly.

Comment: @paparazzo because i need to use the values of recently inserted Rates and Quantities in the same select statement. If there is a better way then please guide me towards it. :)

Comment: But you are not using value(s) from the first cte in the second.

Comment: @paparazzo https://stackoverflow.com/q/49584549/9139132 is why I am using CTE1

Comment: I give up.  CTEs add no value here.  You can just insert directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in `CTE2` is that you have an extra comma at the end of this line:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY,(SELECT r.CheckinDate FROM dbo.Reservation AS r WHERE r.ReservationId=@MinReservationId), (SELECT r.CheckOutDate FROM dbo.Reservation AS r WHERE r.ReservationId=@MinReservationId)) AS NewQuantity,
```

A sidenote: I suggest not writing explicit column names in the future but rather just naming them as you already did with the `AS` keyword. It just gives more flexibility overall.

Answer (score 0):

Because your 2nd CTE defines two columns:

```
CTE2(NewRoomCost,NewQuantity) AS
```

But your select statement returns 3.

```
(SELECT roomRate.RoomCost FROM...

DATEDIFF(DAY,(SELECT r.CheckinDate...

(SELECT r.CheckOutDate FROM dbo.Reservation...
```

Comment: Isn't `(SELECT r.CheckOutDate FROM dbo.Reservation...` enclosed inside `DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )`

Comment: I believe you only have an extra comma at the end of DATEDIFF.

Comment: @MK_  Yes, and it feels so stupid :| I cant delete the question cuz repeated deletion would prevent me from asking future question. Ugghh!! I am just going to edit it in the question.

Comment: @SudeepShrestha - It's quite alright, mistakes like this tend to happen. I suggest me writing an answer, you marking it as the solution and that'll be case closed. :)